# Proving that $x^{2x}<(2x-1)^{2x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, number-comparison

I came across a problem that asks me to prove that $\log_2(3) > \log_3(5)$ and I ended up needing to prove that : $$ x^{(2x)} < (2x-1)^{(2x-1)}$$
 for $x > 1$.
I tried to solve it but i couldn't.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I think you need to prove that $\ln^2(2n-1)>\ln{n}\ln(2n+1)$ for any $n\geq2$.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler approach to the original problem:

$3^2>2^3 \Rightarrow \log_2(3) > \frac 3 2 \\5^2<3^3 \Rightarrow \log_3(5) < \frac 3 2 \\ \Rightarrow \log_2(3) > \log_3(5)$

Comment: I posted it already. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to prove that:
$$\ln^2(2n-1)>\ln{n}\ln(2n+1)$$ for any natural $n\geq2$.

For any $n\geq3$ it's true by AM-GM:
$$\ln{n}\ln(2n+1)\leq\left(\frac{\ln{n}+\ln(2n+1)}{2}\right)^2=\ln^2\sqrt{2n^2+n}<\ln^2(2n-1).$$
By the way, your inequality follows from the following.
$$\log_23>\frac{3}{2}>\log_35.$$
The left inequality it's
$$3>2^{\frac{3}{2}}$$ or
$$9>8.$$
The right inequality it's $$3^{\frac{3}{2}}>5$$ or
$$27>25.$$

Answer (score 0):

Then $x^{2x} < (2x-1)^{(2x - 1)}$ would follow from $x^{2x} < (2x)^{(2x - 1)}$, so attempting

$$x^{2x} < (2x)^{(2x - 1)}$$
$$\log_2 \left(x^{2x}\right) < \log_2\left((2x)^{(2x - 1)}\right)$$
$$2x\log_2 x < (2x - 1) \left(\log_2 2 + \log_2 x\right)$$

Can you finish?